# Is there a tool to mass rename variables/methods for javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a big chunk of obfuscated code that has weird names for variables and I wanted to rename some variables that are used in the code a lot, but since the code is extremely large it would take ages to edit all the code by hand. So I'm looking for some kind of tool that would allow me to rename a certain variable and/or method for a whole source file.
And I don't want to rename all occurrences of a string, I'm looking for a tool that finds all the **references** of a var or method and renames them.

Example:
I want to change variable "a" to "three" without having to do it by hand
(I know there are only 3 instances where the variable "a" is used, but this is just an example)

```
var a = 3;
function printStuff(){
console.log(a+1);
console.log(a/3);
console.log(a*2);
}
printStuff();
```

Comment: All code editors / IDEs have `Find/Replace` tools (except Notepad maybe)

Comment: What editor/ide are you using?

Comment: Im using Visual studio code

Comment: here's a helpful guide on refactoring with visual studio code.
https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code

Comment: im not looking for a simple renamer, im looking for a tool that renames all references of a var or method

Comment: @user5513686 That's what the Refactor command does.

Comment: o didnt see it thx XD

Answer (score 0):

Cred to Rafael Kennedy

[johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code](http://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code) says to use F2 to change a symbol(change a variable name and update it throughout file).